# multithread race condition with use-counted shared pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an old C++98 code base with a combine use-count and pimpl design that's worked fine for years until 4-way and 8-way processors have became common. In the pimpl code you see this (It's actually a template in the real code):

```
class Foo {
    FooImpl* impl;
public:
    Foo() : impl(0) {}
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& foo) {
        if (foo.impl) foo.impl->addRef();
        if (impl && impl->removeRef()) delete impl;
        impl = foo.impl;
        return *this;
    }
    // etc
}
```

The problem is in a multiprocessor environment, task switching can occur between the `if (foo.impl)` and `foo.impl->addRef()`. The first idea to fix this might be:

```
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& foo) {
        FooImpl* fooimpl = foo.impl;
        if (fooimpl) fooimpl->addRef();
        if (impl && impl->removeRef()) delete impl;
        impl = fooimpl;
        return *this;
    }
```

But that doesn't solve the problem. `foo.impl` can still become invalid by the time you call `addRef()` Is there any way around this issue that does no involve some kind of semaphore? If every assignment operator on the objects is wrapped in a semaphore performance will be negatively impacted.

```
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& foo) {
        global_lock.acquire();
        if (foo.impl) foo.impl->addRef();
        if (impl && impl->removeRef()) delete impl;
        impl = foo.impl;
        global_lock.release();
        return *this;
    }
```

I suspect the answer is "no".

Comment: You wouldn't want to use a global lock, but one in the foo object so that it was only locked when messing with the particular instance of foo.  That would reduce contention to where it might be acceptable.

Comment: Global to the class doesn't make it any less global.

Comment: Not class, object.  Each foo object contains its own mutex.

Comment: Shall we assume that, although 4x and 8x core platforms are now part of the mix, you're still relegated to using C++98-only features?

Comment: Use atomic operations to increment and decrement the ref counters. Look into the headers to see how your implementation's version of `shared_ptr` works. Or Boost shared_ptr if you don't have a shared_ptr.

Comment: The real problem is that you seem to be trying to copy objects while another thread is modifying them. You should not do that.

Comment: @ZanLynx, `shared_ptr` does not support concurrent reads and writes to the same object. If you copy a `shared_ptr` it assumes that noone else is assigning to it (or otherwise modifying it) at the same time. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That very document you linked contains references about using or disabling the Boost lock-free atomic counted shared_ptr implementation. If concurrent access wasn't supported then explain why Boost needs an atomic ref-count. Hmm?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: It is much the same as the GNU libstdc++ implementation of ref-counted std::string, which is safe to copy between threads.

Comment: @ZanLynx, the refcount updates need to be atomic so that concurrent updates to distinct objects do not introduce races ('Different shared_ptr instances can be "written to" (accessed using mutable operations such as operator= or reset) simultaneosly by multiple threads (**even when these instances are copies, and share the same reference count underneath**.))', that doesn't mean concurrent updates to a single object are safe. They are not. Neither is copying an object while another thread is modifying that same object. That's exactly the same rule as for the libstdc++ `std::string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reference counting scheme, the objects need to be designed and used in a way that you can guarantee that **it is always safe to add a reference**. As a thought experiment as to why this should be the way it works, consider two threads with a reference to the same object. In such a scenario, there should never be a case where one of the threads experiences the reference count for the object transition to 0, *because its own reference should prevent that from happening.*

In the problem you are describing, the solution should be that the task that is passing the reference to a different task can go ahead and add a reference pre-emptively. Below is a scheme that illustrates this:

```
class FooImpl {
    friend class Foo;
    unsigned count;
    FooImpl() : count(1) {}
    void addRef() { ++count; }
    bool removeRef() { return !--count; }
};

class Foo {
    FooImpl* impl;
    void addRef() { if (impl) impl->addRef(); }
    void removeRef() { if (impl && impl->removeRef()) delete impl; }
    void swap(Foo &foo) {
        FooImpl *tmp = impl; impl = foo.impl; foo.impl = tmp;
    }
public:
    ~Foo() { removeRef(); }
    Foo() : impl(0) {}
    Foo(const Foo &foo) : impl(foo.impl) { addRef(); }
    Foo& operator=(Foo foo) { swap(foo); return *this; }
    // etc
};
```

Note, while the same `FooImpl` instance may be referenced by multiple threads, the scheme requires that each thread maintains its own `Foo`.

Comment: The object "foo" in the operator= can be being assigned while I'm assigning it to some other var. The "foo.impl" in the if returns the original "foo" implementation but when "foo.impl->addRef()" executes, "foo" is now pointing to a different implementation. The issue is there is no guarantee that the "foo.impl" that appears three times in the operator= is the same foo.impl each time. (I suppose it should be marked volatile... hmmm.)

Comment: Your bold statement only applies WITHIN the implementation class. My issue is that it is not always safe to add a reference OUTSIDE the implementation class.

Comment: Change your assignment operator to pass in a copy rather than a reference.

Comment: Yes. This looks like a job for copy and swap. Pass the assignment operator a copy of Foo. `swap(foo, *this)`. Then let foo destroy itself on exit. You may have to create a swap function. It looks like it can just swap the impl pointers.

Comment: @Zan, How do you make a copy when the pointer can be invalid between reading the pointer and dereferencing it without using a lock?

Comment: Unask the question. Why are you trying to read and write the same object concurrently anyway? The code will be much simpler and safer if you don't do that.

Comment: @JW It's perfectly safe with a lock. I'm asking if it can done without a lock. Apparently, it cannot, as I speculated in the question. Simpler is a matter of opinion. With locks, the user doesn't have to worry if the object is writable/readable before access.

Comment: If you need lock-free access to `FooImpl` for performance, then change your software to not share the same `Foo` instance between threads. The important object is `FooImpl` anyway, so I am not sure why you are ignoring the suggestion.

Comment: @jxh because I want to verify that I"m not missing something. My stated question is a YES/NO question. This discussion verifies that the answer is NO. The solution is to do something else: either use a lock or prevent the race with required coding style. But before moving to one of those situations, I wanted to be sure they were the only choices. I'm not ignoring suggestions. I ONLY wanted an answer to the YES/NO question. I knew ahead of time the two trade offs if the answer were NO. If the answer were YES, that would have been "better" but the answer is NO.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. I think the important message in the answer is to never share "Foo", only share "FooImpl" through "Foo". I don't think not sharing Foo is a 100% solution, but it is certainly in the high 90s and careful coding in the edge cases will probably make going mostly lock-free possible. Thanks, everyone.